# Implementing a multiplier in a statistician class

Tags: c++, math, statistics, double

I am working on a programming assignment for my data structures class and we are working on making a statistician class. One of the functions that we have to have is to be able to take a statistician list (count, sum, min, max and mean) and multiply it by a certain integer. Below is what i have so far for the specific function. However, i am lost about where to go as it seems to be worng.

```
statistician operator *(double scale, const statistician& s)
{
    scale*s;
    return s;
}
```

Attached is the .h file that explains what i am trying to do. i am writing the implementation file for this .h file and am trying to figure how to write the statistician operator* that is defined in the comments of the .h file

http://www.cs.colorado.edu/%7Emain/projects/stats.h

Thanks for any help

Comment: So far you haven't done what the problem asked. You have items in a list that needs an operation applied to EACH item. It would seem that you would need to access each list item from the list in the operator...

Comment: Try to fix your question.  First scale * s shouldn't have any effect.  Also, you aren't really asking a question.  What is the operator* supposed to do specifically?  statistician is a class specific to your code.  What is it supposed to represent?

Comment: This specification is too vague - we can guess what the actual problem says, but it would be much more helpful if you told us more clearly.

Comment: "take a list.. and multiply it by a certain integer." Ok, so what does that **mean**? Break it down step by step, and implement that. (BTW, if you are supposed to multiply by an integer, then why is `scale` a `double`?)

Comment: Seeing a desire to multiply statisticians, I cannot resist the urge.  "Old statisticians do not die: they are merely broken down by age and sex."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to create a copy of the class statistician, but scaled by scale.  Something like

```
statistician operator *(double scale, const statistician& s)
{
    statistician result(s);
    result.total *= scale;
    result.tinyest *= scale;
    result.largest *= scale;
    return result;
}
```

The member function scaleBy would multiply the appropriate member variables by the appropriate scale.

You wouldn't scale the count.  If you had something like variance in your statistician class, you would probably multiply it by the square of scale.

Comment: I was attempting to not give away all the details since it looked like a homework question. :)

Answer (score 2):

The code you wrote looks like it will compile, but causes an infinite loop, since it calls itself.  `scale*s` is a shortcut for `operator*(scale, s)`, which is the function currently being defined.  You need to replace the line `scale*s` with baby-steps for the compiler.  It'll look something like:

```
statistician operator *(double scale, const statistician& s)
{
    statistician result
    result.count = /*???*/;
    result.total = /*???*/;
    /*etc*/;
    return result;
}
```

Once that's defined, you may also want `statistician*double`, which can simply do what you've programmed as `double*statistician` like so.  (Note that it doesn't need to be a friend class, since it only calls public functions)

```
statistician operator *(const statistician& s, double scale)
{
    return operator *(scale, s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to implement the operator inside the class, or outside of the class? Read up on [Operators in C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++), and decide!

Comment: i have updated my description in hope that it explains more what I'm trying to do. I am a beginner and am not fully grounded yet.